# Fetching list of locked AD users throws error. Am I using incorrect search terms?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, locked, userprincipal

first of all, I'm fairly new to programming in general. I'm working on a simple monitoring tool.

I'm trying to get a list of all locked AD users. Thanks to stackoverflow I found someone who once had the same question, unfortunately his answer does nog work for me. And I can't really figure out why, but I think I am nog searching correctly.. Below code throws the following error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr75R.jpg)

(Roughly translated: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: IdentityValue)

Tried searching an alternative for "Domain Users" in below code but no luck.

```
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 
IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
```

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
"domainname"))
            {
                GroupPrincipal grp = 
GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, 
"Domain Users");
                foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
                {
                    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 
IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        if (user.IsAccountLockedOut())
                        {
                            lockedUsers.Add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which version of the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement package are you using?

Comment: Version 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue, and the error is in the following line: `var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);` You are trying to find an identity by the `SamAccountName` because the second argument to the `FindIdentity`-method is the identity type to filter by but you are supplying a `UserPrincipalName` instead of a `SamAccountName`. The following options would solve your issue:

`var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName);`

or:

`var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.SamAccountName);`

Comment: You're right, it works now. Thank you for taking the time to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think is the impact performance wise? Since it basically goes by every user in said domain I think..

Comment: I think there is no noticeable performance difference between the 2 methods in my answer. Maybe your code could be improved on overall but I would have to dive in a bit